# Зачем Reselect если есть Memo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

В родительской компоненте

```
mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: getData(state) //тут мы передаем селектор
    }
}
```

В дочерней

```
const Child = (props) => React.memo((props) => {
    //дочерняя компонента
    {props.data}
});
```

Зачем же нужны селекторы, если в дочерней компоненте используется Memo?
Когда их нужно использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `memo` в реакте позволяет избежать лишние рендеры компонента и позволяет рендерить компонент заново только если у него изменились входящие пропсы или стейт. `reselect` выполняет ту же самую работу и был сделан ещё до появления в реакте `memo`. Вы же можете использовать любой подход.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, что сейчас актуально использовать?

Comment: reselect уже не актуально, да как и сам Redux, правда во многих компаниях его используют до сих пор и требуют при приёме на работу. И даже новые проекты с  ним пилят.